# Solving Numerical Integration Implicitly in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, numerical-integration

I am working on constant temperature hot-wire anemometry in Matlab. So I am using a second order differential equation (conduction equation).

I solved the main equation analytically and found temperature distribution:

```
f=0.09;
b=0.0044;
q=3.73E-9;
L=1;
Tw=250;
Tam=27; 

T(x)= 2*C1*cosh(x*((f-b*g)/q)^0.5)+g/(f-b*g)
```

Then `C1` has to be determined from a boundary condition:

```
T(+L/2)=0
T(-L/2)=0
```

Then I found `C1` as a function of `g` (because `g` is implicitly unknown):

```
syms c g
solve(2*c*cosh(0.5*(0.09-0.0044*g)/3.73*10^-9)^0.5+g/(0.09-3.73*10^-9*g)==0,c)
```

`g` can be determined from constant temperature condition:

```
1/L*int(T(x)dx,-L/2,L/2)=Tw-Tam
```

All things considered, my all code is:

```
clc;
clear all;
f=0.09;
b=0.0044;
q=3.73*10^-9;
L=1;
Tw=250;
Tam=27; 

syms c g
c=solve(2*c*cosh(L/2*(0.09-0.0044*g)/3.73*10^-9)^0.5+g/(0.09-0.0044*3.73*10^-9)==0,c)

syms x
z=int(2*c*cosh(x*((f-b*g)/q)^0.5)+g/(f-b*g),x,-L/2,L/2);

g=solve(z==L*(Tw-Tam),g)
```

This condition should give,after performing the integral, an algebraic equation for `g`. But the resultant `g` is zero. It always returns `g` as a zero. Why?  My Matlab skills are not enough for this. I then want to plot the temperature distribution T(x). `x` can be divided into 100 parts of length `L` to plot the temperature distribution.

Comment: You seem to be mixing equations and code (e.g., `cosh{}` is invalid Matlab) which makes your question hard to read/understand. Please edit it. StackOverflow doesn't support TeX so try to just post your actual code. Also, inserting numeric values into a formula too early can make solving it harder in some cases(especially for floating point values). Finally, "I could not perform it" means nothing. Why? Was there an error? Did you not understand something?

Comment: I am really new user for Matlab. I know what I want to do it but I could not translate into Matlab language. So I try to find g value. but I do not know how to write T(x) into constant temperature condition and solve numerically and find g.

Comment: Horchler, 1/L*int(T(x)dx,-L/2,L/2) is not 0 , is equal to Tw-Tambient, also it is not important. On paper it takes too much time because just C1 is so long. I solved second oder ode conduction eqn and I find temperature distribution. I do not know C1 and g in that equation. Then I use boundary condition to find C1. I find C1 which includes g. Then to find g, I have to use constant temperature condition. And I want to do that with Matlab. That is What I need

Comment: what do you think about all code horchler ? why is g always zero ? It shoul not be zero

Comment: Order of operations: `.../3.73*10^-9` should be `.../3.73e-9`. And your equation for T(x) at top doesn't match with the others in terms of `g` and `q`. If you're going to plug in a bunch of numeric values there's probably no sense in using symbolic math. You might better use `fzero`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get zero (assuming that I have your equations correct now). Perhaps you're not substituting in your values properly. You can use the [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) function to do this automatically:

```
f = 0.09;
b = 0.0044;
q = 3.73e-9;
L = 1;
Tw = 250;
Tam = 27;

syms c x g
T = 2*c*cosh(x*((f-b*g)/q)^0.5)+g/(f-b*q);
c = solve(subs(T,'x',L/2)==0,c);
z = simplify(int(subs(T,'c',c),x,-L/2,L/2));
g = solve(z==L*(Tw-Tam),g)
```

which returns

```
g =

20.135660961656472105004196502187
```

You can use `double` to convert this to floating-point. And you can check that this value of `g` does indeed solve your equation:

```
eval(subs(z-L*(Tw-Tam),'g',g))
```

which returns `0`.

Comment: Horchler, you are right man. Thank you. I jump the next level of my problem. Now I fight with Green's function. Do you know how I can approach the Green's function ? 
My new equation is 
qT1''(x)-T1(x)*(f-b*g+i*w*p)=T*(f1-b*g1)-g1
And my prof say that can be solved with Green's function G(x,y)
q*G''(x,y)-G(x,y)*(f-b*g+i*w*p)=Diract(x-y)                
How Can I find G(x,y) ?  Do you know anything about that ?

Comment: And How can I plot temperature distribution T(x) for my first question ? I tried x=linespace(-5,5,100) then plot (x,T) . But it does not work.

Comment: @CanYusuf: You're welcome. Those are all separate questions. If this answer has been helpful/useful to you, you should vote it up and accept it. The idea of StackOverflow is to help you help yourself so you can learn how to solve problems in general. It is not to do your exact problems for you. Please, take some time to do research. Read the documentation carefully. Watch some tutorial videos. Try some things out. Play around. Then if you have a specific question, write it up clearly (not like you did here at first) and provide example code of what you've tried.